# How to display card buttons conditionally?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using new Oracle APEX card region, I have two buttons which should be displayed depending on row data. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add a button in a cards (using new card region).

1. Using "Actions". In this case the "server side condition" can be bound to the row data. For example if I have a card region on the `EMP` table the server side condition of "Item = Value" with item = `ENAME` (column name) and value = 'KING' would only make the button visible for the record of the employee named 'KING'
2. Using 'Template Directives'. This is when you display the button in one of the sections (title/subtitle/body/secondary body). To achieve this, toggle "Advanced Formatting" of the region and put your own markup in it. A button can be built using the button builder in the Universal Theme application and the display can be controlled using template directives. Note that in this case you'll have to submit using a dynamic action. Read more on template directives [here](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2020/11/04/apex-template-directives/) or in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/apex.util.html#.applyTemplate)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't know that I can use column as an item :)